# XAML 2 ComboBoxes Color Styles with Resource Dictionary?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, combobox

**With the help of @ebattulga this has been solved.**

I created a Resource Dictionary with multiple template overrides. http://pastebin.com/nt3FxkM4

And an example visual studio project to download https://www.dropbox.com/s/20mpnbi27xv7nny/ComboBoxColors.zip?dl=0

The following keys have Red and Blue added to the end of name:

- ComboBoxToggleButton
- ComboBoxTemplate
- ComboBoxEditableTemplate

[image: ComboBox Red & Blue]

---

**I have 2 ComboBoxes. I need to make one Red and one Blue.**

I've made an example project below.

Changing the background color in Brush Properties doesn't work. You need to override the Default Template Style LinearGradientBrush ComboBox.Static.Background which is grey and white.

Using Edit Template I can override the Default brush to change them all Red. But I cannot find a way to create another Style to make the other Blue.

I'm trying Resource Dictionary, but the Style does not take effect.

[image: ComboBoxes]

**XAML 2 ComboBoxes**

```
<Window x:Class="ComboBoxColors.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ComboBoxStylesDictionary.xaml"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxRed" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxRed}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="109,105,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxBlue" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxBlue}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="286,105,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Resource Dictionary**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBoxRed.Static.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1.0"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxRed.Static.Border" Color="Red"/>
    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxRed" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxRed.Static.Background}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxRed.Static.Border}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
    </Style>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBoxBlue.Static.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0.0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="1.0"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxBlue.Static.Border" Color="Blue"/>
    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxBlue" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxBlue.Static.Background}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxBlue.Static.Border}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

**C#**

I have also tried this, but resource not found.

```
Brush ComboBoxRedStyle = (Brush)Application.Current.FindResource("ComboBoxRed");
ComboBoxRed.Background = ComboBoxRedStyle;
```

And this with no effect.

```
ComboBoxRed.Background = Brushes.Red;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare resource in App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="ComboBoxStylesDictionary.xaml"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

Or if you only use it in locally, use this

```
Style ComboBoxRedStyle = (Style)this.FindResource("ComboBoxRed");
```

Comment: Moving from <Window.Resources> to <Application.Resources> had no effect on applying the style.

C# Brush FindResource gives cast object error. http://i.imgur.com/pZLEXfj.png

I've uploaded the example to dropbox if you will try it. Anyway way to make one red, one blue. https://www.dropbox.com/s/20mpnbi27xv7nny/ComboBoxColors.zip?dl=0

Comment: Your problem is in "FindResource function return Style class. You cannot convert it to Brush. When you wrap it to Brush it must be null"

Comment: I see, I have used it like you show without converting to brush, and it launches without error, but it still does not apply Red to the combobox.

Comment: You cannot change Combobox background style simply set style. Because combobox Control Template is overriding your style. Therefore you expand Combobox style completely with Control Template using `Microsoft Blend`. Then change border background inside toggleButton. If you want, i can add full template

Comment: If you can do that to the example dropbox file or paste template code somewhere, thanks.

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsCi5LqLBak8odYUDvtUOHjoGSvH2A   I'm changing your code

Comment: How to make the other blue now? I have been able to change the main ComboBox Control Template Red before, but I need the other blue.

Answer (score 0):

In XAML, use it like this,

```
<Page>
    <Page.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="GiveFileName"/>
    </Page.Resources>
</Page>
```

Comment: Error: The property "Content" can only be set once.